# Cucumber java - Adding a string from .txt file to cucumber step definition

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I'm very new to programming so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to create a new scenario that will allow me to input a phrase found in a text file. What I currently have in my stepdefinition file works fine but what I would like to do is edit the text file between each run of Cucumber. Then the search term can be changed without editing the feature file. The text file only needs to contain one line.

This is my current code:

```
@And("^I enter into input field (.*) the search term (.*)$")
    public void i_enter_into_input_field_the_search_term(String field, String value) throws Throwable {
        // searches the text written in search.txt
        field = removeDoubleQuotes(field);
        value = removeDoubleQuotes(value);
        System.out.println("I enter inptu input field:"+ xpath.get(field) + " and : "+ value);
        WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath.get(field)));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys("cucumber help needed");
    }
```

Comment: Cucumber utilizes Gherkin `.feature` files. In the `.feature` file you have multiple options to provide various input, e.g. Data Tables. Not sure why use a `.txt` file but if that's a requirement I guess just read the file :) There's a bunch of how-tos on the subject if that's what you're after.

Comment: This question could be clearer. For example, scenarios are found in feature files, not step-definition files. Also, when you say "alter the phrase in a .txt file" do you mean that you want to edit the text file between each run of Cucumber, or do you want to have multiple input values in the text file and have Cucumber process each of them?

Comment: @JDelorean Thanks a bunch! If you could point me toward a few of those tutorials I would really appreciate it. The more learning the better.

Comment: @Seb Rose I would like to be able to edit the file between each run of cucumber, I will update the question.

Comment: @ErinGlidden A lot of results in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+file+java) will give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: @ErinGlidden Here's [another](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/).

Comment: @ErinGlidden - what requirement leads you to prefer editing a text file to editing the feature file (which is only a text file with a `.feature` extension)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about why you need a .txt file to change anything between runs of cucumber. Are the changes you want to make predefined?

You seem to be running substituting the field and value parameters from your .feature file into your tests successfully which is solid. So I assume you have scenarios like

```
Scenario: I expect this thing to happen
Given some initial step 
And I enter into input field FIELD1 the search term VALUE1
Then I expect this thing to happen
```

So then if you want to rerun the same scenario just with different values, write another scenario like so, and cucumber will just reuse the code which matches that step definition. You don't need to write another one, i_enter_into_input_field_the_search_term will just get re-reun.

So your feature file would look like:

```
Scenario: I expect this thing to happen
Given some initial step 
And I enter into input field FIELD1 the search term VALUE1
Then I expect this thing to happen

Scenario: I expect that thing to happen
Given some initial step 
And I enter into input field FIELD2 the search term VALUE2
Then I expect that thing to happen
```

..etc..etc..

In other words, if you know ahead of time what fields and values go there as part of your scenarios, just list them all out in your feature file (rather than a .txt) to cover all your scenarios.

Am I missing something ?
Hope that helps.

Comment: @ErinGlidden - since this answered your question you should also consider `Scenario Outline`s

Answer (score 0):

If you're always reading from the same file you can use [Files.readAllLines(path, charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) to read the files contents and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the @Josh's answer, you can use `Scenario Outline`s to make very similar scenarios more readable.

For example the two scenarios in his answer are functionally equivalent to:

```
Scenario Outline: I expect things to happen
  Given some initial step 
  And I enter into input field <Field_Name> the search term <Value>
  Then I expect this thing to happen

  Examples:
  | Field_Name | Value  |
  | FIELD1     | VALUE1 |
  | FIELD2     | VALUE2 |
```

You can then create more scenarios by adding extra rows to the `Examples` table. See the [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#keywords) for more details.